# CakePHP and Ajax request url

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I am currently using ajax in multiple controllers in my application. I implemented the ajax functionality using the jQuery supported version.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'getCountries',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data:"data=" + result,
    success: function(data){
                    //magic...
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see from the code above the url of this request is 'getCountries'.
This means that if the request is made from

```
http://localhost/appname/controllername/methodname
```

the request url will be

```
http://localhost/appname/controllername/getCountries
```

However if the url you are using this script is different than in example above, say

```
http://localhost/appname/controllername/methodname/7
```

(like in the edit view), then the request url in the ajax call from those urls will change to

```
http://localhost/appname/controllername/methodname/getCountries
```

How can I make it so that the request url will be generated automaticly depending on the controller I am currently in?

Please note that the **appname** in the url path is the name of the root folder of the application and it should be also included so that if the files will be transported to a different server/location the javascript link will stay consistent with the root folder also.

Comment: So what is preventing you from actually using a full URI for the `url` value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 $.ajax({
url:"<?php echo $this->webroot . $this->params["controller"]; ?>/yourAction"
});
```

`$this->webroot`  contain path to your webroot
for example if your app folder located in htdocs/test
and you mast access it using `localhost/test/` `$this->webroot` will contain following string `'/test/'`

Comment: It's best to generate URLs via the [HtmlHelper::url()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url), this will make sure that custom routes will also be taken into account. i.e. `echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'controllername', 'action' => 'actionname', 0 => $id), true);`. The second parameter (`true`) makes sure that a full URL (http://) is generated, however this is *not* required if you're pointing to the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use full path in your Ajax call and if you use this code in multiple views you could pass ControllerName in some variable:

```
$.ajax({
       url: http://localhost/appname/<?php echo $controllerName; ?>/getCountries
       // code
});
```

In this case you need to use View or Element files (with *.ctp extension) to echo variable to JavaScript code. Alternatively you can echo it to some JavaScript variable in the view and pass it to you external *.js script file.

It works for me in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'controllername', 'action' => 'methodname',7));
```

Will output;

```
/controllername/methodname/7
```

in js

```
$.post({url : "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'controllername', 'action' => 'methodname',7)); ?>"})
```